# How to install a previously generated apk in different devices without rebuild?

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin

I'm currently developing an android app on Android Studio and I'm using physical and emulated devices ([Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/)) to test my application. But every time I want to execute my app in some device I have to build ( wich takes about 2 minutes) the app before install it in device, so if I'm using 3 devices, it will take about 6 minutes to install the app in all of them. Is there a way to build the app one time and pass the same generated **apk** to all devices without rebuild everytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hit build, in 'Device Chooser', you can select more than one device to run on at once. You can do this in a variety of ways (Windows in parentheses):

- Command + A (ctrl + A): select all
- Command + left click (unsure): add clicked to selection
- Shift + left click (ctrl + left click): select all between selected and clicked
- Shift + arrow up/down (ctrl + arrow up/down): add to selection (up/down)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually install the apk, by transferring it from your project folder to your device, but I am not sure if that is what you want.

The apk can be found in the following directory, just go to your Application folder and navigate to:

```
Application\app\build\outputs\apk
```